# Couldn't execute ESQL.EXE to determine the ESQL/C libraries

Tags: perl, informix, dbi, perl5.30

I am building perl 5.30 from source code. I successfully build perl.
Now i am trying to build DBD::Informix with my perl.
All the esql test compiled successfully  but its failing when going for library.

perl Makefile.pl

The error which i am facing on console is
"

> Determining which Informix libraries etc to use... MZÉ$@: not found
>   £èE°êE°δèM°Ç┴êM°δδ¡╢ò≥√  ╢äΦ·  ïMïü╞╟à⌠√  ╕╟ñäG╟¿äGí╝⌐F╕╟î║G╟î║G╟î║G╟⌠çG╕çφïM∞╛QëUⁿïE⌠QïR ╨┌GtBïM∞╛QâΓâ·t3ïE∞╛Hâßâ∙t$ïU∞╛BâαthLâ∙:
>   not found jh₧%  Φî╧  âδïUΦâΩ: not found"

The code which giving error is :

```
"my $esqlscript = (-f $esql) ? $esql : "$ID/bin/esql";
my $libs = `$Perl -pe 's/^\\s*exec/echo/' $esqlscript | sh -s -- -o pseudonym $esqlc_flags dbd::ix.o`    || die "Couldn't execute $esqlscript to determine the ESQL/C libraries\n";
```

Note: I am using Informix client SDK 3.50."

Any help would be appreciable.Thanks

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: I think the Makefile.PL script automatically checks for a valid Informix environment, but just in case, I suggest to check that your esql works before trying to use it. Try something like "esql esqlbasic.ec"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This esql esqlbasic.ec works on my env.

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes i am on windows

Comment: hmmm.. for what I see in the source, support for Windows was removed in the latest versions. which version are you trying? 2015.1101 or below?

Comment: As the author ("Guardian" in my signature blocks) of DBD::Informix, I can tell you that it did once more or less work on Windows NT platforms back in the day — the day being circa 2002 when NT was still more or less appropriate as the designator (XP was the new kid on the block). Since then, it has not reliably been maintained on Windows — though I've done nothing to proactively break support. So, you are on a journey of investigation. Can we safely assume you're using DBD::Informix 2018.1031? We should probably take this discussion to email — the official support channel for DBD::Informix.